# pandas dataframe create new columns and fill with an external API response as calculated using concertinaed values from same df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, rows

```
df=
   User   id
0  u1  id1
1  u2  id2
2  u3  id3

user_limit1=api('u1:id1')

new_df=
   User   id     user_limit
0  u1     id1    user_limit1
1  u2     id2    user_limit2
2  u3     id3    user_limit3
```

how can i update df as above for about 9800 rows of DF ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a column and use `apply` on rows

```
df['user_limit'] = df.apply(lambda x: api_call(f'{x.User}:{x.id}'), axis=1)
```

OR

```
df['user_limit'] = df.User + ':' + df.id
df['user_limit'] = df.user_limit.map(api_call)
```

Note: Ensure that the `api_call` function returns only one value